# custom metric function with additional parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
def custom_metric(y_prem):
   def score_func(y_true, y_pred):
      diff = y_pred - y_true
      return tf.reduce_sum(diff[y_prem>=y_pred])
   return score_func

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=[len(X_train[0, :])], activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=[len(X_train[0, :])], activation='linear'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=[len(X_train[0, :])], activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=[custom_metric(y_prem)])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train_minmax, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=len(y_train))
```

y_prem and y_train are both the same size(50646)

I have tried to define this custom metric function where y_prem is a vector in the size of the prediction. I want to sum the diff between the pred and the true only on the indexes where the pred is lower than y_prem but when I trained the model I received an error message:

```
File "C:/Users/zehavi kelman/PycharmProjects/Accident_predicting/simpego_test.py", line 61, in score_func  *
        return K.sum(diff[y_prem>=y_pred])

    ValueError: Shapes (50646, 1) and (50646, 50646) are incompatible
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what you want to do but I implemented a reproducible example that do not output an error message (pay attention to the `x` and `y` shapes):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(shape=[50646, 5], minval=0, maxval=1)
y = tf.random.uniform(shape=[50646, 1], minval=0, maxval=1)
y_prem = tf.random.uniform(shape=[50646, 1], minval=0, maxval=1)


def custom_metric(y_prem):
    def score_func(y_true, y_pred):
        diff = y_pred - y_true
        return tf.reduce_sum(diff[y_prem>=y_pred])
    return score_func

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=[len(x[0, :])], activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='linear'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=[custom_metric(y_prem)])
model.summary()
model.fit(x, y, epochs=30, batch_size=len(y))
```

Comment: yes i have tried it gave me the same problem. i edited now the main message to add more details

Comment: You don't need `input_shape` for the hidden layers. And with an output layer with 1 neuron, the output tensor last dimension size must be 1.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the comment.
yes i mistakenly copied the command input_shape multiple times but yet when i delete it, it stays with the same problem.

the problem is in the command y_prem>=y_pred and i dont understand why

Comment: I updated my answer but not knowing what you exactly want to compute, it is hard to understand what to implement.

Comment: so the problem was indeed because of shape issues - when i reshaped it to (50646,1) instead of (50646,) it worked!

thanks!